# Debian - How to get this job in cron.d to run at startup

Tags: linux, gnome, cron

Using Debian Jessie, I'm having trouble running a one line file I placed in /etc/cron.d

The file contains the following line:

`@reboot myuser /usr/bin/keepass2 /home/myuser/mydb.kdbx -pw:password`

It is meant to open my keepass database, logged in and to be run as myuser rather than root.

I found [this question here](https://superuser.com/questions/664454/why-doesnt-my-cron-d-per-minute-job-run) which seems to be exactly my problem. As per comments to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/664474/409217) I changed permissions of the file in cron.d to the following:

`-r-----r-- 1 root root  73 Jun 12 09:26 keepass`

However it still doesn't seem to work. `run-parts --test /etc/cron.d` returns an empty line. And it doesn't run at startup either.

Comment: Are you sure you want this to run at boot?  This means it won't have a GUI to run in.  It would be better to run it as part of ubuntu startup wouldn't it?

Comment: Hi @Paul, my main aim is to give iceweasel access to the keepass database on startup. I'm not overly familiar with linux... where would be the appropriate place to add this line? Cheers

Comment: For some reason I thought it was Ubuntu - what desktop environment, gnome, kde or something else?

Comment: No worries, I'm on gnome

Comment: I am out of touch with Gnome, try this: https://gnomeshell.wordpress.com/2011/08/28/manage-the-startup-applications/

Comment: This looks promising, thanks for that, will try this later on at home

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the fact that *keepass* is a graphic utility, and using cron to start it at boot does not guarantee that your WM has started yet.

The way to deal with this is to use [kpcli](http://kpcli.sourceforge.net/), a keepass CLI utility available also on Debian (just checked).  It has many available commands, but the one you need is:

```
   kpcli open file.kdb file.key &
```

Alternatively, you may start keepass as the very last command at boot, by placing the keepass startup command as the last line (except for the *exit 0*) in */etc/rc.local*.